# Filter rows which does NOT contain a certain string

Tags: r

Considering that I have a dataframe (3+ Million rows) (**df**) with a column named as **Text** containing a sentence in each row. I want to filter the data in a way that it **excludes** those rows which have certain keywords.

I know that if you want to filter a dataframe if it has some certain strings you can do as follows:

```
df <- df %>% filter(grepl('first|second', Text))
```

And this will filter the rows **including** first and second as keywords only.

How can I filter the rows **excluding** the above two keywords?

Comment: ``filter(!grepl('first|second', Text))``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `!` before your `grepl` like this:

```
df <- df %>% filter(!grepl('first|second', Text))
```